# Siri Voice Feedback Not Functioning on iPhone 6 (iOS 9)

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

I have an **iPhone 6 running iOS 9** – Siri has become speechless all of a sudden. It appears to have went dumb; there is **no voice feedback whatsoever**.

Siri answers all of my questions correctly with an on-screen response, but there is no voice feedback at all. Can this be sorted without a restore?

**PS:** I have already performed a Soft Reset.

Answer (score 1):

Voice feedback can be enabled/disabled in Settings -> General -> Siri.

Comment: It's enabled, else Siri just won't turn up. Mine is working fine but not speaking.

Comment: You can not only enable Siri there, but also the voice feedback (second to last option on the page).

Comment: Voice feedback is set to Always

Answer (score 1):

This issue (essentially a "silent Siri") appears to be prevalent with many iPhone 6 devices running iOS 9. Which language are you currently using Siri with?

A full restore of the iPhone may not be necessary. First, invoke Siri and ensure the **volume is turned up**.

Next, please can you attempt **resetting the Network Settings** first, by visiting:

> Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings

Please attempt to invoke Siri after resetting the Network Settings. If this does not solve your issue, you may need to **reset all device settings** (your apps and data will remain unaffected).

To reset all device settings, please visit:

> Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings

Unfortunately, if these minor resets are unable to alleviate the issue, I would advise a **full restore** of your iPhone, as this appears to be the sole remaining solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue (which wasn't fixed through [general troubleshooting](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207489)) and fixed it by changing to a different voice.

"Settings", "Siri & Search", "Siri Voice".

---

UPDATE: The voice switched back to the previous voice on its own, and it is now working.

I prefer the previous voice, but I'm assuming it is corrupted somehow. There doesn't seem to be a way to delete and reinstall the voice (without a full restore). I'm optimistic that a new iOS update will eventually fix the voice automatically, so I can switch back to that voice.